# Do you know what this stack trace means?

Tags: ios, stack-trace

Unfortunately there is a bug in my App I can't reproduce but my user's can see it. My Logging software unfortunately only gives me this to work with.

This occurs when the user logs in but it dosn't give me any clues as to why this occurs.

PRIMARY THREAD THREAD 0

```
            0 uKash 0x000ce446 testflight_backtrace + 382
            1 uKash 0x000cf094 TFSignalHandler + 264
            2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394c9e92 _sigtramp + 42
            3 uKash 0x00137fe4 CLSSignalHandler + 196
            4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394c9e92 _sigtramp + 42
            5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394c0122 pthread_kill + 58
            6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394fc972 abort + 94
            7 libc++abi.dylib 0x38a9ad4e abort_message + 74
            8 libc++abi.dylib 0x38a97ff8 _ZL17default_terminatev + 24
            9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3904ba76 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 146
            10 libc++abi.dylib 0x38a9807a _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 78
            11 libc++abi.dylib 0x38a98113 _ZSt9terminatev + 19
            12 libc++abi.dylib 0x38a99598 __cxa_current_exception_type + 0
            13 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3904b9d0 objc_exception_rethrow + 12
            14 CoreFoundation 0x31269f20 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 456
            15 CoreFoundation 0x31269d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            16 GraphicsServices 0x34e422ea GSEventRunModal + 74
            17 UIKit 0x3317f300 UIApplicationMain + 1120
            18 uKash 0x0008065a main (main.m:17)
            19 libdyld.dylib 0x39482b1f start + 3
            Hide Other Threads

            COM.CRASHLYTICS.MACHEXCEPTIONSERVER

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            COM.APPLE.NSURLCONNECTIONLOADER

            0 CoreFoundation 0x312f6da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
            1 CoreFoundation 0x31269ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            2 CoreFoundation 0x31269d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            3 Foundation 0x31bb63d4 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 308
            4 Foundation 0x31c39e84 __NSThread__main__ + 972
            5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            COM.APPLE.CFSOCKET.PRIVATE

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            THREAD 13

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            THREAD 10

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            THREAD 11

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            THREAD 14

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            WEBTHREAD

            0 CoreFoundation 0x312f6da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
            1 CoreFoundation 0x31269ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            2 CoreFoundation 0x31269d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            3 WebCore 0x3727d504 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 444
            4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            THREAD 8

            0 CoreFoundation 0x312f6da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
            1 CoreFoundation 0x31269ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            2 CoreFoundation 0x31269d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            3 Foundation 0x31b8cf96 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
            4 Foundation 0x31c30864 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
            5 uKash 0x0008d8c8 +[AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (AFURLConnectionOperation.m:151)
            6 Foundation 0x31c39e84 __NSThread__main__ + 972
            7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            THREAD 9

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            THREAD 12

            0 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394978a3 start_wqthread + 7
            THREAD 1

            0 0xffffffff 0xffffffff
            THREAD 4

            0 CoreFoundation 0x312f6da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
            1 CoreFoundation 0x31269ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            2 CoreFoundation 0x31269d48 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
            3 Foundation 0x31b8cf96 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 254
            4 Foundation 0x31c30864 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 80
            5 uKash 0x000e468c -[TFNetworkManager networkRunLoopThreadEntry] + 124
            6 Foundation 0x31c39e84 __NSThread__main__ + 972
            7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            THREAD 7

            0 CoreFoundation 0x312f6da2 __CFRunLoopRun + 882
            1 CoreFoundation 0x31269ebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
            2 CoreFoundation 0x312c89ba CFRunLoopRun + 98
            3 uKash 0x00102802 +[UA_ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (UA_ASIHTTPRequest.m:4794)
            4 Foundation 0x31c39e84 __NSThread__main__ + 972
            5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a2310 _pthread_start + 308
            6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x394a21d7 thread_start + 7
            LOAD ADDRESS

            0x0007f000

            REGISTER VALUES

            cpsr: 16
            exception: 0
            far: 950698525
            fsr: 7
            lr: 1277925
            pc: 961841208
            r0: 0
            r1: 0
            r10: 9
            r11: 2145364
            r12: 37
            r2: 1
            r3: 989958088
            r4: 802691172
            r5: 0
            r6: 802691236
            r7: 802691140
            r8: 6
            r9: 989915304
            sp: 802691112
```

Comment: The crash happened because an exception occurred. Since the crash report does not show Last Exception backtraces, it is impossible to know where it happened. And since this report does not show the Exception reason either, there is nothing more that can be said about this crash. It seems you also have crashlytics installed, maybe their reports are more helpful. You should check those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have both Testflight and Crashlytics crash handlers in your app.

If you aren't getting good information out of Testflight, check your Crashlytics account for better crash reports. In our experience we get good crash reports from Crashlytics but similarly unhelpful stack traces from Testflight when we have both SDKs active, and Crashlytics is initialized last.

Comment: So what do you recommend? Change the order or remove one?

Comment: We use Crashlytics for crash reporting and TestFlight for other test data. So for us it's ok that TestFlight doesn't have good crash reports, and we leave Crashlytics initialized last.

If you find TestFlight is interfering with Crashlytics, see http://www.grahamdennis.me/blog/2012/10/21/how-to-disable-testflights-crash-handlers/ for how to disable TestFlight's crash handler.

If you want good crash reports in TestFlight, remove Crashlytics or experiment with loading TestFlight last.

Comment: I read the docs, and since v.2 you can ```[TestFlight setOptions:@{TFOptionReportCrashes: @NO}];```

Answer (score 0):

You need to symbolicate the crash report is pretty easy using Xcode organizer, you just need to drag into it (device tab). For more there is an [Apple Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html). 
After that we can understand better the crash.
It seems something realted to connections, and probably test flight.

Comment: This does not apply here! This crash report is already symbolicated to Testflight standards. Also it is not in a format, that Apple tools can symbolicate it anyway, since Testflight uses its own custom format.